# jquery how to modify an image's attr

Tags: jquery

How to modify an image's attr use jquery? I want set the `image's height` as the `window.height`

http://jsfiddle.net/wyCqT/

```
<script type="text/livescript">
$(document).ready(function(){
   var height = $(window).height();
   $('img').attr('height',height);
});
</script>
<img src="http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6124/6022097678_4477a09976_o.jpg" />
```

Comment: Your fiddle works perfectly for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could use:

```
$('img').attr('height', $(window).height());
```

[JS FIddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wyCqT/1/)

Or you could use `prop()` in place of `attr()`:

```
$('img').prop('height', $(window).height());
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/wyCqT/2/)

But both of these are variations on what you've already written, the problem you're having is that you've used `type="text/livescript"` in your `style` tag, if you amend that to: `style="text/javascript"` it works.

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).
- [`height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/).

Answer (score 0):

You should not change the height attribute, you should change the height css.

And for window height in particular you can just do:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

Then add:

```
style="height: 100%;"
```

To your image and you don't need to mess with jQuery at all.